# How do I set a Date to a javascript object, using Java?

Tags: javascript, java, datetime, datepicker

I am using Java and Eclipse. For one part of my project, I needed to write a calendar, so I decided to use already written (on javascript) callendar - http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

I have written a method that initialize the js component:

```
private static native void initComponent()/*-{
        $wnd.$('#datetimepickerStart').datetimepicker();
        $wnd.$('#datetimepickerEnd').datetimepicker({
                                            value:'29.06.2015',
                                            format:'d.m.Y.H:i'});
    }-*/;
```

The problem is that I dont know how to populate the date. I tried something like:

```
private static native void setStartDate(Date date)/*-{
        $wnd.$('#datetimepickerStart').datetimepicker({
                                            value:date,
                                            format:'d.m.Y.H:i'});
    }-*/;
```

But it didnt work.

Can I have some suggestions: what I have did right/wrong, what to google?

Comment: This is actually GWT / Google Web Toolkit, isn't it?

Comment: So you are now fixing your tags and your question to reflect that missing information, right?

Comment: @Gimby, yes exactly. I am not familiar with javascript, and I thought that maybe I am populating the Date object in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use another programming language just inline in the Java code.
Despite it's name, JavaScript has not much in common with Java.

If you really want to integrate both, you could do so using the [Java Scripting API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/) but that is going to be tough.

Comment: I am doing this with native method, and it works fine. I just don't know how to parse the Date object.